# How to check each row for invalid values/codes in a data.frame

Tags: r, validation, match

Can I know how to check if there's invalid codes in dataframe in R?

I would like to check is if the variables for Code1 to Code5 is matching with my pre-defined codeframe/list.

All the valid values in my pre-defined codeframe/list:

```
1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11
```

Below is my data frame

```
Key  Code1  Code2  Code3  Code4  Code5                 
 1    1      8      15     NA      11         
 2    5      3      NA     NA      NA
 3    4      5      11     NA      NA            
 4    11     2      NA     NA      NA
```

and would like to have result as below

```
Key  Code1  Code2  Code3  Code4  Code5   Result                 
 1    1      8      15     NA      11    FALSE    <-due to invalid code "15"        
 2    5      3      NA     NA      NA    TRUE
 3    4      5      11     NA      NA    TRUE            
 4    11     2      NA     NA      NA    FALSE    <-due to invalid code "2"
```

Can anyone help with it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the rows, then use `%in%` to check whether all the non-NA elements in that row is found in the vector ('v1')

```
df1$Result <- apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] %in% v1))
df1$Result
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11)
```